# find specific text on a webpage using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get the last page number of the manga from [this](https://readms.net/r/onepunch_man/083/4685/3) webpage, the dropdown list on this page has a string `'Last Page(57)'`. I want to find the last page number using Beautiful Soup.

```py
import bs4 as bs
import requests

ref = requests.get('https://readms.net/r/onepunch_man/083/4685/3')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(ref.text, 'lxml')

#FIND OUT THE LAST PAGE NUMBER FROM THE SOURCE CODE!!!

print(soup.find_all(string='Last Page')
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: No error. This just doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use :contains to get the `a` tag with `Last Page` in `innerText`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r  = requests.get('https://readms.net/r/onepunch_man/083/4685/3')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
last_page = int(soup.select_one('a:contains("Last Page")')['href'].split('/')[-1])
```

Less robust:

You could positional match with

```
.btn-reader-page li:last-child a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
res = soup.find_all("ul",{"class":"dropdown-menu"})[-1].find_all("li")[-1].text
print(res)
```

output:

```
'Last Page (57)'
```

to find the number use:

```
import re
last_page_number = re.findall("\d+",res)
print(last_page_number)
```

output:

```
57
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `BeautifulSoup`. Simply check page source for `Last Page` item:

```
import re
import requests

r = requests.get('https://readms.net/r/onepunch_man/083/4685/3').text
last_page = re.findall('Last Page \((\d+)\)', r)[0]
```

Output:

```
57
```